# Marketing cloud - SSJS - Truncate Sendable DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce-id, ssjs

I have a sendable DE which i am trying to truncate . however its erroring out.

The code for ssjs is

```
<script runat="server">
     Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
     var rows = Platform.Function.DeleteData("863A1A7D-B737-4B53-81E3-6F49BCC3EE27","Type","1");
```

Also I tried another approach , Added a Type column to DE which is predefaulted to 1 of type text and then used following code to delete rows , this is also failing .

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1");
var Cus_NL_DE = DataExtension.Init("Consumer Newsletter NL - Staging");
var row = Cus_NL_DE.Rows.Remove("Type","1");
```

I am testing by putting the script in automation and running ,

Answer (score 2):

finally got this working ,.

var rows = Platform.Function.DeleteDE("Consumer Newsletter NL - Staging",['DeleteType'],['1']);